# counting the number of sub palindroms in a string, including the string it self

Tags: python

I want to count the number of sub palindromes in a string and count also the string itself if it's a palindrome. Single letters are not palindromes.

Example **input**: RRR

The palindromes here are RRR, and twice RR, so the **output** should be 3.

Another example: **input** rapal

**output**: 1

How can I go over the input with every possible starting point and every possible ending point? only this way I'll get every palindrome in the input. This is my attempt of doing it:

```
my_input = input() 

first_char = my_input[0]
last_char = my_input[len(my_input)-1]
num_of_pol = 0

for i in range(0, len(my_input), 1):
    for j in range(len(my_input)-1, 0, -1):
        while (i <= j):
            first_char = my_input[i]
            last_char = my_input[j]
            if (first_char == last_char):
                continue
            
print(num_of_pol)
```

Comment: You don't consider single letters to be palindromes? BTW: there is no question here. You just state what you want to do and provide code. That's it. No problem statement, no question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it right now. And no, single letters are not palindromes. only two letters and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- `num_of_pol` is never incremented
- if the `while (i <= j)` loop is entered, execution will never get out of it, because neither `i` nor `j` are modified in the loop. So this represents an infinite loop. In each iteration the same characters are compared.
- `continue` is useless when it is the last statement in a loop's body. It signifies that the *rest* of the code in the loop's body should be skipped, but as there is none, that is already the behaviour without that `continue`. So the body of the loop does the same thing whether or not the two characters are equal.
- Not a problem, but the middle loop could have its range stop at `i` instead of 0. We are not interested in iterations where `j <= i`, so they can better not be generated at all by limiting that `range`.

The idea of the inner loop surely is to check whether the sublist represents a palindrome. For this you should have a loop variable -- let's call it `k` -- so that you are free to increment it without affecting the other loop variables (`i` and `j`). This innermost loop variable would represent how far from the two ends the character should be considered and compared.

When these two characters are *not* equal the inner loop should stop -- as it is clear the sublist is not a palindrome. You can use a `break` statement for that.

If the loop can finish without encountering a `break` then a palindrome was found and your counter can increment.

Here is the correction of the loops in your code:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_input), 1):
    for j in range(len(my_input)-1, i, -1):
        for k in range(1 + (j - i) // 2):
            first_char = my_input[i + k]
            last_char = my_input[j - k]
            if first_char != last_char:
                break
        else:  # this executes if there was no break
            num_of_pol += 1
```

#### Efficiency

Your algorithm is not the most efficient. It can be made more efficient if you would iterate over the possible **centers** of the potential palindrome (which can be *on* a letter, or *between* two consecutive letters). Then you can *extend* outward from that center, until you don't have a palindrome any more. This way you efficiently count all palindromes that have the same center.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated. Your suggested algorithm is interesting, but why do you think it's more efficient this way? For example, if the input is abcdefgggg, your suggested algorithm won't work, it won't capture the palindrome on the side, which is why I need to find every possible start and end. Or, perhaps I'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: It would get all those on the side too. The idea is that you consider every possible center of a potential palindrome, and then for each of those centers start expanding outward.